# how to make query, to view column to become row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, how can I make a query so the result is like the picture below?

In the below image, the left-hand side is the first condition, and the right one is the desired result:

[image: left site is the first condition, the right one is the result hoped]

Thank you.

Comment: You've tagged this with _sql-server_ but the tables you've included are in Excel.  Is this based on a database table or something else?

Comment: Will there always be at most 4 groups of data per row?

Comment: If it is SQL Server please provide the query and some sample input and output data.

Comment: This is a simple UNPIVOT or CROSS APPLY... MY PROBLEM is that you have Date and City columns repeating.   What does the actual source look like ?

Comment: thanks to @dale burrell, OK, I'll try,

Comment: thanks to @Lee Mac, It can be more than 4 groups of data per row

Comment: thanks to @martin parkin, this is based on sql, the picture is just the example of the data

Comment: thanks to@john cappelleti.  
in the header, there are repeating columns (date dan city), 
actually, this is a history about the cities visited, and when it happed.
=> date1, city1, date 2, city2 , date3, city3....

Comment: Try to use unpivot

Comment: Im sorry,  the header of collumns should be:

Comment: I'm sorry, 
the table name is hitory, the header of the collumns should be IDCARD, NAME, Date1, City1, Date2, City2, Date3, City3, Date4, City4

I've tried it :
select idcard,name, date from history unpivot(date for detail in (date1,date2,date3,date4)) as unpvt    => success

But I'm still not able for this script:
select idcard,name, date,city from history unpivot(date for detail in (date1,date2,date3,date4),city for detail in (city1,city2,city3,city4)) as unpvt
Thanks a lot for all..